# Problems with Output, Shiny app R

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make a Shiny application which allows you to search for a term in Twitter and then to analyze the feelings of tweets obtained and calculate the percentage of positive and negative tweets. I have all the implemented functions but I can not write the results on screen. The function that calculates the percentages is void, in other words,  returns nothing, what do I do to display the results on screen?

In ui.r:

```
sidebarPanel(textInput("term", "Put the term",""),
textInput("number","Number of tweets",""), submitButton("Search")),
mainPanel(("Results of the search"),textOutput("result"))
```

In server.r:

```
myterm<-reactive({myterm<-TweetFrame(input$term, input$number)})

cleanterms <- reactive({CleanTweets(myterm()["text"])})

sentimentsTweets<-reactive({sentimentsTweets<-sentimentalanalysis(cleanterms()["text"])})

output$result <- renderPrint({paste(print(sentimentsTweets()["score"]))})
output$result <- renderPrint({CalculatePercentaje(as.vector(sentimentsTweets()))})
```

I wish I knew how to write for display tweets score obtained and how to write the results of calling the function CalculatePercentage, this is the function:

```
CalculatePercentage<-function(sentimentTweets){

      neutral <- 0
      negativo <- 0
      positivo <- 0

      for(i in 1:length(sentimentTweets$score)){

        if(sentimentTweets$score[i] == 0){
          neutral <- neutral + 1 
        } else {
          if(sentimentTweets$score[i] > 0){
            positivo <- positivo + 1
          } else {
            negativo <- negativo + 1
          }
        }

      }

      cat("El porcentaje de tweets neutrales es ", (neutral * 100)/ length(sentimentTweets$score), "% \n")
      cat("El porcentaje de tweets positivos es ", (positivo * 100)/ length(sentimentTweets$score), "% \n")
      cat("El porcentaje de tweets negativos es ", (negativo * 100)/ length(sentimentTweets$score), "% \n")
}
```

Comment: I could make this work if I had the function "sentimentalanalysis"

Comment: Ok, I explain you, the function returns a matrix of two rows, the first of which is the score that is given to each tweet contains depending on whether positive or negative words and second row contains the text of each tweet.

Comment: Code please. Or try it out in the template I posted below as an answer.

Comment: the function receives a vector with the contents of each tweet, really, you don´t need to know the content of the function because my question is how do I write the results of the function on screen?

Comment: I have posted the code of the function

Comment: Ok, have to take care of something now, will come back to it. You could give me a point for effort already though :).

Comment: No problem, thanks for your interest, score.sentiment is a auxiliar function that was used by sentimentalanalysis to check the sentiment of tweets. This functions return a matrix with 2 rows: The first is the score of the tweets and the second row is the text of the tweets. My problem is how do i write this matrix on screen. I always have the same error : String must be an atomic vector

Comment: Ok, it compiles and outputs stuff. I edited some stuff to make it work (got rid of CleanTweets. It works. Please accept it if it works for you. An upvote would not hurt either.

Answer (score 0):

This can get you started, but I don't have enough pieces to finish it and get it to work.

ui.R:

```
  shinyUI(
    sidebarPanel(textInput("term", "Put the term",""),
             textInput("number","Number of tweets",""), 
             submitButton("Search"),
             mainPanel( h4("Results of the search"),
                        textOutput("result1"),
                        textOutput("result2"))
    )
  )
```

server.R

```
library(stringr)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  score.sentiment = function(sentences, pos.words, neg.words) {

    # we got a vector of sentences. plyr will handle a list
    # or a vector as an "l" for us
    # we want a simple array ("a") of scores back, so we use 
    # "l" + "a" + "ply" = "laply":
    scores = laply(sentences, function(sentence, pos.words, neg.words) {

      # clean up sentences with R's regex-driven global substitute, gsub():
      sentence = gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', sentence)
      sentence = gsub('[[:cntrl:]]', '', sentence)
      sentence = gsub('\\d+', '', sentence)
      # and convert to lower case:
      sentence = tolower(sentence)

      # split into words. str_split is in the stringr package
      word.list = str_split(sentence, '\\s+')
      # sometimes a list() is one level of hierarchy too much
      words = unlist(word.list)

      # compare our words to the dictionaries of positive & negative terms
      pos.matches = match(words, pos.words)
      neg.matches = match(words, neg.words)

      # match() returns the position of the matched term or NA
      # we just want a TRUE/FALSE:
      pos.matches = !is.na(pos.matches)
      neg.matches = !is.na(neg.matches)

      # and conveniently enough, TRUE/FALSE will be treated as 1/0 by sum():
      score = sum(pos.matches) - sum(neg.matches)

      return(score)
    }, pos.words, neg.words)

    scores.df = data.frame(score=scores, text=sentences)
    return(scores.df)
  }
  sentimentalanalysis<-function(entity1text){

    # A compiled list of words expressing positive and negative sentiments ----
    #http://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/sentiment-analysis.html
    # List of words and additional information on the original source from Jeffrey Breen's github site at:
    #https://github.com/jeffreybreen/twitter-sentiment-analysis-tutorial-201107/tree/master/data/opinion-lexicon-English

    positivewords=readLines("positive_words.txt")
    negativewords=readLines("negative_words.txt")

    #Applying score.sentiment algorithm to cleaned tweets and getting data frames of tweets, net sentiment score for a tweet 
    #(number of positive sentiments minus negative sentiments)

    #entity1score = score.sentiment(CleanTweets(entity1text),positivewords,negativewords)
    entity1score = score.sentiment(entity1text,positivewords,negativewords)

    return(entity1score)

  }  
  TweetFrame <- function(term,number)
  {
     s <- sprintf("%s%s",term,number)
     return(s)
  }

myterm<-reactive({myterm<-TweetFrame(input$term, input$number)})

#cleanterms <- reactive({CleanTweets(myterm()["text"])})
cleanterms <- reactive({myterm()["text"]})



sentimentsTweets<-reactive({sentimentsTweets<-sentimentalanalysis(cleanterms()["text"])})

output$result1 <- renderPrint({paste(print(sentimentsTweets()["score"]))})

CalculatePercentage<-function(sentimentTweets){

  neutral <- 0
  negativo <- 0
  positivo <- 0

  for(i in 1:length(sentimentTweets$score)){

    if(sentimentTweets$score[i] == 0){
      neutral <- neutral + 1 
    } else {
      if(sentimentTweets$score[i] > 0){
        positivo <- positivo + 1
      } else {
        negativo <- negativo + 1
      }
    }

  }

  cat("El porcentaje de tweets neutrales es ", (neutral * 100)/ length(sentimentTweets$score), "% \n")
  cat("El porcentaje de tweets positivos es ", (positivo * 100)/ length(sentimentTweets$score), "% \n")
  cat("El porcentaje de tweets negativos es ", (negativo * 100)/ length(sentimentTweets$score), "% \n")
}

output$result2 <- renderPrint({CalculatePercentage(as.vector(sentimentsTweets()))})
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

score.sentiment = function(sentences, pos.words, neg.words)
    {

```
  # we got a vector of sentences. plyr will handle a list
  # or a vector as an "l" for us
  # we want a simple array ("a") of scores back, so we use 
  # "l" + "a" + "ply" = "laply":
  scores = laply(sentences, function(sentence, pos.words, neg.words) {

    # clean up sentences with R's regex-driven global substitute, gsub():
    sentence = gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', sentence)
    sentence = gsub('[[:cntrl:]]', '', sentence)
    sentence = gsub('\\d+', '', sentence)
    # and convert to lower case:
    sentence = tolower(sentence)

    # split into words. str_split is in the stringr package
    word.list = str_split(sentence, '\\s+')
    # sometimes a list() is one level of hierarchy too much
    words = unlist(word.list)

    # compare our words to the dictionaries of positive & negative terms
    pos.matches = match(words, pos.words)
    neg.matches = match(words, neg.words)

    # match() returns the position of the matched term or NA
    # we just want a TRUE/FALSE:
    pos.matches = !is.na(pos.matches)
    neg.matches = !is.na(neg.matches)

    # and conveniently enough, TRUE/FALSE will be treated as 1/0 by sum():
    score = sum(pos.matches) - sum(neg.matches)

    return(score)
  }, pos.words, neg.words)

  scores.df = data.frame(score=scores, text=sentences)
  return(scores.df)
}






sentimentalanalysis<-function(entity1text){

  # A compiled list of words expressing positive and negative sentiments ----
  #http://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/sentiment-analysis.html
  # List of words and additional information on the original source from Jeffrey Breen's github site at:
  #https://github.com/jeffreybreen/twitter-sentiment-analysis-tutorial-201107/tree/master/data/opinion-lexicon-English

  positivewords=readLines("positive_words.txt")
  negativewords=readLines("negative_words.txt")

  #Applying score.sentiment algorithm to cleaned tweets and getting data frames of tweets, net sentiment score for a tweet 
  #(number of positive sentiments minus negative sentiments)

  entity1score = score.sentiment(CleanTweets(entity1text),positivewords,negativewords)

  return(entity1score)

}
```